# function assignment error in a vector(R language)

Tags: r, function, dataframe, vector

i need to find the number 35 in x and assign it a function.
Then call the function.
code:

```
x  <- 1:100
z  <- 0

z[x == 35]  <- function() { # error here 
    
    print("hello")

}

z  <- max(z, na.rm=TRUE) # remove all NA in vector

z() # run it
```

error:

```
Error in z[x == 35] <- function() { :
   incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
```

Thanks!!

Comment: what is z supposed to be? You first assign 0 to it and then you try to get its 35th element which doesn't exist and to assign it a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite why you'd want to do it, but...

```
x  <- 1:100
z  <- list()

z[[which(x == 35)]]  <- function() {
  print("hello")
}

z[[which(x == 35)]]() # run it
[1] "hello"
```

The key is to use a list, not a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
z  <- function(x) {  
    print("hello")
    max(x, na.rm=TRUE) # remove all NA in vector
  }


for (x in 1:100){
  if (x == 35){
    z(x)
  }
}
```